# iOS grouped or normal tableview for categories

Tags: lists, ios, categorization

So I have tableview where I got different categories for huge amount of items. Would it make more sense to put the categories in grouped tableview or in a normal, or does it matter at all?

Comment: Some more information would be helpful. When to do it one way vs. another way really depends on the context. I'll provide some thoughts in an answer but they'll be fairly general.

Answer (score 2):

Some things to think about:

- Does the user need to access a certain group of records more frequently? Perhaps then a grouped view with this group at the top will be best.
- Does the user need to look at multiple records in the table view and compare them? What groups of items do they need to look at? If this is grouped by a single field, then displaying grouped tables may make more sense.
- Do different fields create groupings that matter to different user users, or matter at different times? Perhaps a general-purpose grouping is not the answer, but column sorting may work better.
- How many records are part of table? Will they all be displayed on the same page or paginated? If you are paginating records then groups may provide an additional cue to keep track of place.
- How much space do you have for columns? pulling a field out to define a group will give you more horizontal space.

Comment: Well. I will post image soon.